# Сброс потока в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Для сброса потока  в *bootstap* используют клас  `.clearfix` . Что это такое и причины использования я прекрасно понимаю .

В документации написано следующее:

> В дополнение к очистке столбца на адаптивных точках, вам может
>   понадобиться сброс *offsets*, *pushes*, или *pulls*.

Что такое сброс *offsets*, *pushes*, или *pulls*? Где и как их использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы знаете ответ на ваш вопрос, просто наверняка не догадываетесь :). 
Для сброса *offsets, pushes, или pulls* на **Адаптивных точках** не какой магии не надо.
Например у нас есть такой элемент у которого размер пол ширины радит. элемента на [md-size](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) , md-offset-3 , md-push-3:Все эти стили будут работать когда у нас [Медиум девайс](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

```
<div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-md-push-3'>
```

для сброса на **Адаптивных точках**(то есть сбросить параметры где нам не понадобится offset или push) надо к ниму добавить col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-push-0 (конечно место *xs* можем ставить любой размер ), в итоге получится такое

```
<div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-md-push-3 col-xs-offset-0 col-xs-push-0'>
```